# Problems receiving "large" TCP messages

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy

I have problem receiving TCP messages where the size is more than 8000+ (probably 8192) bytes.

Do anybody know what I am doing wrong or missing? Can it be a buffer or timing problem?

The code (below) works perfectly for messages below this "limit".

The first 64 bytes of a message is a header containing the total message length. Only the first 16 bytes of header is direct readable.
Byte 0 is 0x46 ('F')
Byte 1 is not handled at this point
Byte 2 and 3 is message length after header.
Byte 4-7 is not handled at this point
Byte 8- 15 all zeros.
Byte 16-63 and data after header is encrypted.

Every message is acknowledge by the receiver using sequence numbers.
When either part send an new message it increases it's sequence number.
There is only one message from either part active at the same time, before next message can be sent the previous have to be acknowledged.

If the sequence numbers don't add up the communication is reset.

It is normal that the messages vary in size, from 64bytes to 10k+.

When receiving large messages, the first message check (beginning with 'F' and length in range) fails and results in return.

The contents of `bytes` is garbage when inspecting (breakpoint at `return` statement).

Inspecting the `IOHandler->InputBuffer` reveals that it then contains valid data (this is however some time after the break).

Using Wireshark (filter : host,no arp), I see that the message sent from the other party is sane. It is split in chunks of 1460 byte and one smaller, all is acknowledge and no other messages occurs.

Code below is lacking message parsing and encrypt/decrypt but otherwise somewhat complete.
To ensure that sequence numbers are maintained/handled properly and acknowlegde messages to remote part is prioritized all receiving and sending is done from this method.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::TCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
   try
   {
      if(AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty())
         AContext->Connection->IOHandler->CheckForDataOnSource(100);

      if(!AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty())
      {
         try
         {
            unsigned short msglen;
            unsigned char* puch = (unsigned char*)&msglen;
            TIdBytes bytes;
            TIdBytes Data;
            int DataLength;
            unsigned char digest[20];

            bytes.Length = 64;
            AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes(bytes,64,false);  // read header
            puch[0]= bytes[3];        // Endianess
            puch[1]= bytes[2];
            msglen = msglen & 0x1FF;  // block count of data section each block 16 bytes maximum 640

            if(bytes[0] != 0x46 || msglen > 640)
               return;

            Data.Length = msglen * 16;

            if(msglen)
              AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes(Data,DataLength,false);   // read data section

           TMessage Msg = ValidMessage(bytes, Data);
           if(Msg->IsAckMsg)
           {
              TList* list = txList->LockList();
              if(list->Count)
              {
                 for(int i=0; i < list->Count; i++)
                 {
                    TMessage* msg = (TMessage*)list->Items[i];
                    if(Msg->RSeqNo == msg->RSeqNo)
                    {
                       list->Delete(i);
                       delete msg;
                       break;
                    }
                 }
              }
              txList->UnlockList();
           }
           else
           {
              TMessage ACKMsg = Msg->MakeACK();
              TIDBytes senbytes;
              int Msglen = ACKMsg->Prepare(sendbytes);
              AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(sendbytes, MsgLen);
              rxList->Add(Msg);
              LogMsg(ACKMsg);
              PostMessage(this->Handle, MSG_UPDATE, NULL, 1);
           }    
         }
         catch(Exception& E)
         {
         }
      }
      else
      {
         TMessage* Msg = NULL;
         TList* list = txList->LockList();
         if(list->Count)
            Msg = (TMessage*)list->Items[0];
         txList->UnlockList();

         if(Msg)
         {
            if(Msg->fMsgSent)
               return;
            TIDBytes bytes;
            int Msglen = Msg->Prepare(bytes);
            AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(bytes, MsgLen);
            Msg->fMsgSent = true;
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception& E)
   {
   }
```

Wireshark summaries

```
Message received correct
1   0.000000    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 342 52000 ? 55496 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=63080 Len=288      // Command request to remote part
2   0.030413    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 117 55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=63     // Command acknowledged by remote part 
3   0.031360    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 60  55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=64 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1
4   0.031444    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55496 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=65 Win=63016 Len=0
5   0.050135    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=65 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460  // Respons from remote part beginning with 0x46 0x01 0x01 0xee
                                                                    // Gives total message length 64 + 494*16 = 7968
6   0.051363    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1525 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
7   0.051424    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55496 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2985 Win=64240 Len=0
8   0.053059    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2985 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
9   0.053860    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4445 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
10  0.053910    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55496 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=5905 Win=64240 Len=0
11  0.055217    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=5905 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
12  0.056023    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 722 55496 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=7365 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=668 // Last response chunk
13  0.056091    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55496 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=8033 Win=64240 Len=0
14  0.056428    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 118 52000 ? 55496 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=8033 Win=64240 Len=64  // Respons acknowledged
15  0.057674    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 60  55496 ? 52000 [ACK] Seq=8033 Ack=353 Win=11680 Len=0

Message not received correct
1   0.000000    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 342 52000 ? 55501 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=62952 Len=288      // Command request to remote part
2   0.034937    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 117 55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=63     // Command acknowledged by remote part
3   0.035910    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 60  55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=64 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1
4   0.035961    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55501 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=65 Win=62888 Len=0
5   0.056781    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=65 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460  // Respons from remote part beginning with 0x46 0x01 0x02 0x33
                                                                    // Gives total message length 64 + 563*16 = 9072
6   0.058048    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1525 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
7   0.058083    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55501 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2985 Win=64240 Len=0
8   0.059735    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2985 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
9   0.060575    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4445 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
10  0.060604    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55501 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=5905 Win=64240 Len=0
11  0.062111    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=5905 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
12  0.063037    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 1514    55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=7365 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1460
13  0.063061    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55501 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=8825 Win=64240 Len=0
14  0.063804    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 365 55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=8825 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=311
15  0.063805    192.168.1.72    192.168.1.202   TCP 60  55501 ? 52000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9136 Ack=289 Win=11680 Len=1   // Last response chunk
16  0.063839    192.168.1.202   192.168.1.72    TCP 54  52000 ? 55501 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=9137 Win=63928 Len=0
No acknowledge as meesage not received correct.
```

Comment: It is very hard to diagnose your problem without knowing the actual protocol you are trying to implement. What is the actual format of the messages, especially the 64-byte header? Rather than using `ReadBytes()` and shifting bytes manually, you should use higher level methods, like `TIdIOHandler.ReadInt16()`, which handle endianess for you. And you definitely should not be using `InputBufferIsEmpty()` and `CheckForDataOnSource()` the way you are. This is not the kind of situation that needs those calls. Just let `ReadBytes()` (or whatever) block until the full requested data is received

Comment: You also didn't include the code that is trying to read a message's remaining data after its 64-byte header. So how do we know that code isn't leaving behind bytes that corrupt the reading of subsequent messages? You need to provide a [mcve] so we can see everything.

Comment: I have edited the post and added more code and prehaps the CheckForData... etc. makes more sense.

Comment: You haven't shown the actual DATA that is failing to be read. Your Wireshark summaries are useless without the packet data. But one thing that I find odd is your use of `msglen & 0x1FF`, which means `msglen > 640` will *never* be true since `msglen` is restricted to 511 max. You describe the `msglen` as being a message length, but you are actually treating it as a block counter instead, denoting a number of 16byte blocks in the message, which doesn't seem to jive with the packet lengths in your Wireshark summaries. Do you have any *documentation* about how this protocol *really* works?

Comment: I see a number of logic bugs in this code in general, the least of which is DON'T catch and discard Indy exceptions, but also you need to use `try..finally` or RAII to lock/unlock your lists *safely*, and you have some potential memory leaks.

Comment: A "message length" of `0x02 0x33` produces an initial `msglen` value of 563 (0x233) in your `puch` manipulation, and then you truncate `msglen` to 51 (0x33) (see [this](https://ideone.com/qGkrlF)) due to the `& 0x1FF` stripping off the high 10th bit, before you then check the message for failure. A mask of `0x1FF` allows for 9 bits, but 563 has 10 bits in it, where the high bit is 1 and gets chopped off. Is that what you really want? Why are you truncating `msglen` with `& 0x1FF` at all?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is enough with other eyes.
The 1FF mask is wrong, when replaced with the correct 3FF it works so far.
Thanks for your  keen eyes.